# How to store channel Id and use it/log it

Tags: discord.js

```
   command(client, 'explore', (message) => {
        const name = message.content.replace('!explore ', '')
        message.guild.channels
        .create(name, {
            type: 'text',
        })
        .then((channel) => {
            const catagoryId = '847950191108554762'
            channel.setParent(catagoryId)
        })

        const channelId = message.guild.channels.id
        console.log(channelId)
    })
```

I'm having an issue with saving the newly created channel's id so that way when the channel is done being used instead of typing the name, I can use the id to be inputted into the deletion command. Basically creating temp. predefined or newly found channels and then being able to log the Id and then with a deletion command be able to remove it without writing a name of the channel.

```
    const channelId = message.guild.channels.id
    console.log(channelId)
```

this was my attempt to retrieve/store then log it. I've been trying to do this on my own but have hit a roadblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a channel’s ID, just type `<Channel>.id`. There are multiple ways to get a channel, here is an example:

```js
const channelID = <Message>.channel.id;
console.log(channelID);
```

The above example gets the ID of the message's channel
Also, `<guild>.channels.id` returns undefined, since guild.channels is a collection of multiple channels, and you can’t just get the id like that. This would be useless if you are trying to get the channel ID since you would have to fetch/get the channel by ID, or use a find method, which could return the wrong channel if there are multiple channels the bot has seen that goes with your condition, so what you are trying to do, it doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: Thank you and ya sorry I'm kinda new to messing with discord.js and definitely took a wrong turn somewhere lol. But thank you for your help.